# SSRS -> Report header changes after uploading to the server.....How can this be fixed?

Tags: reporting-services

I have created my SSRS report in VS2010 and it looks really good.  Upon placing this on the report server the size of the header increases (twofold) and really messes up my styling.

I have tried setting the  property to false.  This did not work at all.  I have researched all over the web and haven't been able to find a solution to this.

Any ideas?

[image]

***Update -> I removed interactive sorting from the header just to see if this was causing the increase in height, it was the culprit.  The size was corrected once I removed interactive sorting.  Problem being, I need interactive sorting.  Also, upon removing the interactive sorting functionality, I could no longer see the text for the headers.  So, I now have a correctly sized header with no text and no sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added in a height for each cell manually and changed the line height.  This fixed this.